# How to select specific parts of a uniformly Colored Figure in openCV Python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have an image of a blue colored cross drawn in MS Paint.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtC9g.jpg

I want to be able to extract the four separate arms of the cross from the image, and store them in four separate images.

What I have tried is to use cv2.inRange() method to detect the color blue, as per the following code :

```py
        import cv2
        import numpy as np
        img=cv2.imread("PECross.png")
        blue=[
        ([250,0,0],[255,0,0])]
        for (lower, upper) in blue:
        lower=np.array(lower, dtype="uint8")
        upper=np.array(upper, dtype="uint8")
        mask=cv2.inRange(img,lower,upper)
        output=cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask)
        cv2.imshow("Out",output)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and then display the extracted blue colors. It extracts the entire cross because its colored the same, but I want to extract the four arms of the cross separately.

**What code do I need to add, to extract the four arms of the cross separately?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code. It uses hough lines to detect lines than simply crops the image regions given by the lines

```
img = cv2.imread('PECross.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
lines_coords = []
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50,150,3)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200)
for rho,theta in lines.squeeze():
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
    lines_coords.append((x1,y1,x2,y2))
vertical_left = lines_coords[0]
vertical_right = lines_coords[1]
horizontal_up = lines_coords[2]
horizontal_down = lines_coords[3]

x1,y1,x2,y2=vertical_left
left_arm = img[:, :x1]

x1,y1,x2,y2=vertical_right
right_arm = img[:, x1:]

x1,y1,x2,y2=horizontal_up
upper_arm = img[:y1, :]

x1,y1,x2,y2=horizontal_down
lower_arm = img[y1:, :]

cv2.imwrite('left_arm.png', left_arm)
cv2.imwrite('right_arm.png', right_arm)
cv2.imwrite('upper_arm.png', upper_arm)
cv2.imwrite('lower_arm.png', lower_arm)
```

Comment: This code worked perfectly, but could you please explain why there are 4 arguments in the cv2.Canny() method call? The documentation https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html  lists only 3 arguments. Also could you explain what are you doing inside the For loop?

Comment: The link you mentioned is not a documentation link. It's a tutorial which only shows one example of canny. [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga04723e007ed888ddf11d9ba04e2232de) is the official link. Hough lines return lines in polar coordinates (r, Ѳ), the loop is just converting those to cartesian coordinates and saving them in a list.